# How to turn multiple lists into a list of sublists where each sublist is made up of the same index items across all lists?

Tags: python, list, merge, sublist

How to turn multiple lists into one list of sublists, where each sublist is made up of the items at the same index across the original lists?

```
lsta = ['a','b','c','d']
lstb = ['a','b','c','d']
lstc = ['a','b','c','d']

Desired_List = [['a','a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c','c','c'],['d','d','d']]
```

I can't seem to use zip here, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of list will give like this:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(lsta, lstb, lstc)]
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c'], ['d', 'd', 'd']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip`, under duress:

```
>>> zip(lsta, lstb, lstc)
[('a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c'), ('d', 'd', 'd')]
```

If Python 3, you'll need to convert the zip to a list:

```
>>> list(zip(lsta, lstb, lstc))
[('a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c'), ('d', 'd', 'd')]
```

Comment: that don't return ('a','a','a','a')

Comment: that is list of tuples, not what the owner want ?

Comment: admittedly not what OP *asked for*, but still likely what OP *wants* :)